# Let TypeScript infer (some or all) generic parameter

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a generic type `Gen<T>`:

```
type Gen<T> = {
    t: T,
    x: boolean,
};
```

And then I have some function that takes in a `Gen` but does not care about the `T` type:

```
function handleGen1(gen) {
    if (gen.x) {
        return gen;
    }
}
```

How would I type `handleGen1`? Currently I can only see this way:

```
function handleGen1<T>(gen: Gen<T>) {
    if (gen.x) {
        return gen;
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way, like in [Flow](https://flow.org/) (`function handleGen1(gen: Gen<*>) { ... }`)?

Also, what if my function depends only on some of the type arguments?

```
type Gen<P, E> = {
  p: P,
  e: E,
  x: boolean,
}

function handleGen2(gen) {
    if (gen.x) {
        return gen.p;
    }
}
```

I would like to type that as:

```
handleGen2: (gen: Gen<P, *>) => P;
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent to the `*` syntax in typescript. The option you found with declaring the type parameter is a good one. Note that at call site the extra parameter does not have to be specified, typescript will infer the apropriate `T`

```
type Gen<T> = {
    t: T,
    x: boolean,
};

function handleGen1<T>(gen: Gen<T>) {
    if (gen.x) {
        return gen;
    }
}

handleGen1({
    t: 1,
    x: true
}) // T infered as number
```

If you have more parameters to `Gen` you will to declare one for each type parameter:

```
type Gen<T, P> = {
    t: T,
    p: P,
    x: boolean,
};

function handleGen1<T, P>(gen: Gen<T, P>) {
    if (gen.x) {
        return gen;
    }
}

handleGen1({
    t: 1,
    p: "",
    x: true
}) // T inferred as number, P number
```

Now if you truly don't use the type parameter in any other position you can go with `Gen<any>` or `Gen<unknown>`. In your example, you do use `T` since the return type is going to be `Gen<T>` so `Gen<any>` will not forward the type parameter. If that were not the case we can use this option:

```
type Gen<T> = {
    t: T,
    x: boolean,
};

function handleGen1(gen: Gen<unknown>) {
    if (gen.x) {
        console.log(gen.t);
    }
}

handleGen1({
    t: 1,
    x: true
}) // works fine 1 is assignable to unknown
```

A disadvantage of having to specify the type parameters is having to specify the type constraint as well.